# Reading a MailMerge field from a Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a *VBA* script that will read the value of a *merge field* in an *MS Word* document. This field's code is:

```
{MERGEFIELD  Vendor_ID \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

I have tried accessing it via [`MailMergeField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmergefield):

```
' No access by ID, must use an index:
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields(1)
```

but this object does not seem to provide the value. I then tried to do the same via [`MailMergeDataField`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.mailmergedatafield), but again in vain, because the document has no data fields, i.e.

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields.Count = 0
```

At last, I endeavored to follow the example from the [`DataFields`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.MailMergeDataSource.DataFields) documentation only to find out that the data source has no records:

```
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount = -1
```

Now I give up and ask your help in reading the value of a merge field. [Here](https://freeshell.de/%7Eantonius/file_host/mm_sample.docm) is a sample document from which I am trying to read the value of the `Vendor_ID` merge field—`400775`. Beware that it already contains some *VBA* code with my failed attempts. The [bookmark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmark) `V_Vendor_Number` comprises that value, but I have an explicit requirement not to use bookmarks.

Comment: The reason you're not getting anything from .DataSource.DataFields is that refers to content in the data source, not in the document.  What is the purpose of reading the mergefield, since that depends on which record you're looking at and the mergefield doesn't exist in the output document?

Comment: The reason for reading a merge field is the customer requirement. They gave me a file like the one referenced in my question and required that I read its contents via merge fields. You say the merge field does not exist in the *output document*. What is an output document? The merge field certainly does exist in my file, does it not?

Comment: @macropod This is a *ping* comment to let you know about my answer  above, where I forgot to mention you.

Comment: Mailmerges employ a mailmerge main document containing MERGEFIELDs to generate a mailmerge output document. When used as intended, a mailmerge main document is connected to the data source for all records. Upon opening such a document you will be presented with a mailmerge SQL prompt. A mailmerge output document typically contains multiple copies of the mailmerge output document, but without the MERGEFIELDs, which will have been replaced by the data for the records concerned. If you're not getting the mailmerge SQL prompt, the document is no longer connected to the data source, if ever it was.

Comment: Some programmers use MERGEFIELDs as nothing more than placeholders in ordinary documents, and write data to the MERGEFIELDs instead of using them in a mailmerge. Either way, if you have a document that present you with a mailmerge SQL prompt when you open it, it isn't connected to a data source. Accordingly, all you're left with is reading through the fields collection to find the one you're interested in. See code in answer below.

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-vba-reading-a-mailmerge-field-from-a-word/58c86845-90a8-4c39-b807-b852f5eafe44. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Comment: @macropod I cannot open that *excelguru* website, but I know that I did wrong: I should have waited longer before cross-posting, and then I should have warned my readers about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a document that doesn't present you with a mailmerge SQL prompt when you open it, it isn't a mailmerge main document and isn't connected to a data source. Accordingly, all you're left with is reading through the fields collection to find the one you're interested in. You can also take the same approach with a mailmerge main document that is connected to a data source. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim Fld As Field
For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
  With Fld
    If .Type = wdFieldMergeField Then
      If Trim(Split(Split(.Code.Text, "MERGEFIELD ")(1),"\")(0)) = "Vendor_ID" Then
        MsgBox .Result.Text: Exit For
      End If
    End If
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe there is a *does not* missing in the first sentence of your answer, which should read: *If you have a document that* does not *present you with a mailmerge SQL prompt when you open it, it isn't a mailmerge main document and isn't connected to a data source.*

Comment: So this is kind of an abuse of merge fields, is it not? And the only method of accessing them is sequential rather than random (by id)?

Comment: «So this is kind of an abuse of merge fields, is it not?» Perhaps mis-use would be more accurate. The problem is that the people who do this then sometimes call what they're doing mailmerges (which they're not) and/or expect the fields in their documents to do calculations and the like they way they would if a real mailmerge was involved. The fields could be accessed by their index # (e.g. ActiveDocument.Fields(2)) but that gets tricky when some fields aren't visible - as in ASK fields - and/or the fields are nested inside others.

Comment: Please, check your method of parsing the field's `.Code`. In my case, the field identifier (`Vendor_ID`) is not the first element in the split string but the third:  
`Trim(Split(f.Code.Text, " ")(3))`

Comment: Your Split implementation is not the same as mine - read it again. The reason I did it that way is because field codes do not always begin with a space. Even your own representation lacks the usual beginning space. And, even with that space, the only reason (3) would work is if someone has manually inserted an extra space somewhere before Vendor_ID (again, not depicted in your representation of the field code).

Comment: With an initial `Trim` I had to write:  
`Split(Trim(f.Code.Text), " ")(2)`, because there are two spaces before the field id (question fixed). I will have to parse it more accurately not to depend on the number of consecutive spaces in the field code.

Comment: It could only be that way because someone messed with the field code. See revised answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not responsible for the creation of that *Word* document and are forced to work with whatever we get. Your revised solution is not so good: why do you not store the result of `Split(StrCode, " ")` in a variable instead of spitting it again and again in every iteration of the `For` loop? I will rather parse that value by a single linear scan. Anyway, the iteration of `ActiveDocument.Fields` of type `wdFieldMergeField` is all I needed to know.

Comment: «why do you not store the result of Split(StrCode, " ") in a variable instead of spitting it again and again in every iteration of the For loop?» Because it's more efficient *and* reliable that way. Given how your document's fields have been used, there could also beVendor_ID1, Vendor_ID2, etc. Testing whether Vendor_ID exists without confirming it isn't Vendor_ID1, Vendor_ID2, etc. could lead to mismatches. Hence, a «single linear scan» would be *unreliable*. Unlike FormFields, there is no MergeField collection you can use for an «iteration of ActiveDocument.Fields of type wdFieldMergeField»

Comment: How can repeated splitting of the *same* string be more efficient and reliable? If each field has exactly one id, I see no way in which the prefix of an id may be mistaken for the whole id in case of single-pass linear scanning. [Here](https://pastebin.com/raw/uVCSAjr2) is my implementation, which I think it much better and faster than yours. If, on the other hand, a single *Field* object may contain a list of several Id's, then I would have to amend it, but it will remain a single-pass scanner of the array of split strings.

Comment: Perhaps you can show me a `{MERGEFIELD...` line that will not work with my algorithm.

Comment: Simple: {MERGEFIELD  Vendor_ID1 \\* MERGEFORMAT} will return a false match. Try the updated answer - no secondary loop.

Comment: When I invoke [my](https://pastebin.com/raw/uVCSAjr2) function with your merge-field code, it correctly returns `Vendor_ID1`—so I still do not understand where you think it may fail. Your revised code is much better now in that it does not much less redundant work. And I think it is very hard to improve further because *VBA* does not let one without tricks access the characters of a string as if it were an array, which is why I didn't write a low-level single-pass scanner, either.

Comment: «When I invoke my function with your merge-field code, it correctly returns Vendor_ID1—so I still do not understand where you think it may fail.» Because Vendor_ID1 *is not* Vendor_ID!!! If you specify Vendor_ID with my code it will not return anything for Vendor_ID1. With your code (or Doug's @ MS Answers) it will, but returning content for Vendor_ID1 is an error. «VBA does not let one without tricks access the characters of a string as if it were an array» but that is exactly how Split treats it...

Comment: I see why Doug's version is defective—he ought at least to have surrounded the search string by spaces. But [my](https://pastebin.com/raw/uVCSAjr2) function will not give false positives, so that you can safely say `If MergeFieldId(field) = "Vendor_ID"` and be certain it will not misfire for `Vendor_ID1`.

Comment: Re: the `Slit()` function: I believe it is implemented internally in the *VBA* interpreter, and not as pure *VBA* code. In *VBA* a string may be converted into an array of bytes, which is useless or grossly inconvenient in case of multibyte encodings. A character at a specified index can be read from a string using the `Substring()` function, but it is *very* inefficient. Similarly, replacing a character in a string is not quick and either in *VBA*.